# Causing a UserControl to remove itself (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dispose

In winforms I usually do `Parent.Controls.Remove(this);` to have a UserControl remove itself.
This isn't working for wpf.
My control has button on it to remove the whole UserControl, any ideas how to accomplish this in wpf?
Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to remove userocntrol, in which is button? what type is the parent container?

Comment: could you provide you XAML markup, to make it clear?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt - A stackpanel is the parent, but I would prefer to keep the control generic and not limited to parent type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to know the type of the `Parent` property to remove yourself from your Parent control.

All Panel type parents (Grid, WrapPanel, StackPanel) have the `Children` property:

i.e. for Grid:

```
((Grid)button.Parent).Children.Remove(this);
```

ContentControls (Button, ContentControl, Border) have Content:

i.e. for Button:

```
((Button)control.Parent).Content = null;
```

Comment: Aaah! I see, thanks! I think casting to a Panel base type is more of a generic fit though :)