# Unloading a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

There must be a simple way of unloading a UserControl from display without using Visibilty, as in theory it's not actually unloaded.

What solutions are there?

Comment: you can call Remove(this) on the Parent's collection which contains your user control, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4254235/559144

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Causing a UserControl to remove itself (WPF)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254213/causing-a-usercontrol-to-remove-itself-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UserControl.Dispose()` as documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc9y48w.aspx

Comment: This applies to `Windows.Forms` not `WPF`